# How can I use leaflet over vue+webpack inside a component?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am making a vue project and I want to use leaflet inside of my components.

```
import L from 'leaflet';

  export default {
    created() {
      L.map('map').setView([33.4501001, -101.9107704], 4); // Coordinates, Zoom
    },
  };
```

html:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <h1> Hello </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="map">

    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

But I get the error `Map container not found`?

Comment: You can find an example on: https://github.com/vicmars5/skycatch-challenge/blob/master/src/components/LocationsMap.vue. It works fine for me.

Comment: mounted() { L.map('map').setView([33.4501001, -101.9107704], 4); // Coordinates, Zoom }

Answer (score 1):

[vue2-leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-leaflet) provides Vue2 leaflet components so you can do things like `<l-map ...><l-tile-layer ...>...</l-tile-layer></l-map>`.

Here's the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/KoRiGaN/Vue2Leaflet).

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has clearly explained the problem yet within the original poster's code, I am posting much later to simply inform the poster that Leaflet cannot find the "map" DOM element yet within the `created` hook and you must simply move the code into the `mounted` hook.

```js
// just change 'created' to 'mounted'

import L from 'leaflet';

  export default {
    mounted() {
      L.map('map').setView([33.4501001, -101.9107704], 4); // Coordinates, Zoom
    },
  };
```